# No instance for (Typeable PackageName)

Tags: haskell, cabal

I try to compile this code:

```
import Data.Typeable
import Distribution.Package

name :: PackageName
name = PackageName "Foo"

main = do
  print $ typeOf name
```

But this fails with this error:

```
No instance for (Typeable PackageName)
  arising from a use of `typeOf'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Typeable PackageName)
In the second argument of `($)', namely `typeOf name'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ typeOf name
In the expression: do { print $ typeOf name }
```

However, both the documentation for Cabal and the source code say that PackageName has an derived instance for Typeable. What am I missing?

ghc version: 7.6.3
cabal version: 1.16.0

Comment: The documentation for [`Cabal-1.16.0.1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.16.0.1/docs/Distribution-Package.html) actually shows there is no `instance Typeable PackageName`. The documentation indicates the this instance first appears in version 1.18.0, so you should install a version later than that one (preferably the latest). (Note that `cabal-install` and the Haskell package `Cabal` are not the same thing and that `cabal-install` is a standalone program not dependent on the package `Cabal`).

Comment: @user2407038: That was actually the problem. I thought I checked that. First I checked the version using `apt-cache show libghc-cabal-dev` and when writing this post I checked the version with `ghc-pkg list`. My failure was that libghc-cabal-dev wasn't installed and the old version shipped with GHC was used... Would you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Cabal-1.16.0.1 actually shows there is no `instance Typeable PackageName`. The documentation indicates the this instance first appears in version 1.18.0, so you should install a version later than that one (preferably the latest). (Note that `cabal-install` and the Haskell package `Cabal` are not the same thing and that `cabal-install` is a standalone program not dependent on the package `Cabal`).